# php single table language separated autoincrements?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have 1 table for posts.
And my columns are
Id | id_language | lang

I want to achieve, that there is a second autoincrement id for its language. For example the 80.post is the 5.post written in english language. I need separate index number for sef url. Is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying you have the same posts available in different languages. Assuming that's the case, I'd split the table in two.

`post` would have the basic info about the post that is not language dependent:

- the unique ID for that post's content
- the ID of the user who wrote the post
- the date the post was created
- ...

`post_language` would be the content for each specific post, translated into a specific language:

- `post_lang_id` - unique ID for this `post_language` row
- `post_id` - foreign key to `post`; identifies the underlying post that his has content for
- `language` (or `language_id`): This can either be the name of the language this content is written in, or a foreign key to a `language` table, with all the languages you've got content in. I'd be inclined to use `language_id`, but it's up to you.
- `post_title`
- `post_content`
- ...

In the `post` table, `post_id` would be the primary key, and an auto-increment value. In `post_language`, post_lang_id` would be the primary key, and an auto-increment value.